# Python: RPM library

Tags: python, rpm

I've got this simple Python script, using `rpm-python-4.11.3-25` module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rpm
import sys

print('Library version: {}'.format(rpm.__version__))
ts = rpm.TransactionSet()
mi = ts.dbMatch()
mi.pattern('name', rpm.RPMMIRE_GLOB, sys.argv[1])
for h in mi:
    print('##### {}-{}-{} #####'.format(h['name'], h['version'], h['release']))
    fi = h.fiFromHeader()
    print("Number of files: {}".format(len([f[0] for f in fi])))
    print(fi.VFlags())

# python test.py httpd*
Library version: 4.11.3
##### httpd-tools-2.4.6-67.el7.centos.6 #####
Number of files: 15
0
##### httpd-2.4.6-67.el7.centos.6 #####
Number of files: 496
0
```

Is there a way to add verification and package owning a file functionality? I believe `rpm.fi` class should help with this but I'm not sure and I can't find any documentation:

```
# rpm -qV httpd
S.5....T.  c /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
.......T.    /usr/sbin/httpd

# rpm -qf /usr/sbin/httpd
httpd-2.4.6-67.el7.centos.6.x86_64
```

Comment: @deceze, what is not clear for you?

Comment: For starters, what package exactly are you using? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rpm…? Probably not.

Comment: You can see this from the import and script is printing version but I've also added version.

Comment: Clearer now. 